# python exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy with python and I have this code in a python item pipline

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        ID = str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, item['link']))
```

I got this error :

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\mid
dleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
            return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\uti
ls\defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
            d.callback(input)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 3
82, in callback
            self._startRunCallbacks(result)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 4
90, in _startRunCallbacks
            self._runCallbacks()
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 5
77, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "General_Spider_code_version_2\pipelines.py", line 7, in process_
item
            ID = str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, item['link']))
          File "C:\Python27\lib\uuid.py", line 549, in uuid5
            hash = sha1(namespace.bytes + name).digest()
        exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in p
osition 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to debug the `item['link']`

and this is the result

```
-> ID = str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, item['link']))
(Pdb) item['link']
u'http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/2014/4/6
/palm-jumeirah-abu-keibal-3-br-maid-partial-2/?back=ZHViYWkuZHViaXp6bGUuY29tL3By
b3BlcnR5LWZvci1yZW50L3Jlc2lkZW50aWFsL2FwYXJ0bWVudGZsYXQv&pos=1'
(Pdb)
```

as you see the `item['link']` is unicode

#### Edit1

when I change the `item['link']` to any other attribute like `item['date']` the code works perfectly

Comment: Decode the unicode URL into bytes with `.decode('utf-8')` and it should work.

Comment: @Blender do you mean `str(..).decode('utf-8')` ? or `str(...item['link'].decode(utf-8))`?

Comment: The second one. You want the link to be a byte string, not a unicode string.

Comment: @Blender still the same error. this is the new code `ID = str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, item['link'].decode('utf-8')))`

Comment: Whoops, I meant `.encode()`, not `.decode()`.

Comment: @Blender yes that works. Many thanks. type an answer to accept it please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Encode the unicode string into byte string with `.encode('utf-8')` and it should work:

```
str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, item['link'].encode('utf-8')))
```