# How do we give an identification to a relationship in OntoRefine RDF mapping?

Tags: relationship, rdf, graphdb, ontorefine

I'm working on a transformation work in which I need to transform a property graph dataset into a RDF dataset. There are so many n-ary relationships that need to be traited as a class, but I do not know how to affect an unique identification on these relations. I tried to use the row index but I've got more than one file on this work so this can't work. **So I would like to know how do you affect an unique identification to relationships**, if the URI is the solution, how do we do this in OntoRefine mapping? Thank you for your answers.

Lee

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to address this:

- Ideally, use some characteristics of the related entities to make a deterministic URL. Eg if you're making a position (membership) node between a person and an org that involves a mandatory role and start date, you could use a URL like `org/<org_id>/person/<person_id>/role/<role_id>/date/<date>`
- Use a blank node. In that case you don't need to worry about a URN
- Use the row index if you prepend it with the table/file name (as a constant)
- Use the [GREL function](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions) `random()`. It doesn't produce a globally unique identifier, but if you ask for a large enough range, it'll be unique with a very high probability
- Use a Jython function, as shown at [How to create UUID in Openrefine based on the MD5 hash of the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083893/how-to-create-uuid-in-openrefine-based-on-the-md5-hash-of-the-values)
- If you do your mapping using SPARQL, then use the builtin `uuid()` function